# Error on .net core project when add Swagger (Only When Publish Project on Server)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger-ui

I have a severe problem with Swagger. When I user Swagger in my project, it works perfectly on Local Machine, but when I publish the program to the server,I get error 502.
I can't find any solution for this problem.

Comment: Check your server logs.

Comment: I can't find any log for this error

Comment: Every error like that should produce something in the logs. If you are using IIS in front of your app, then this could also be an IIS problem so make sure to also check the Windows event log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably use an incompatible version of Swagger in your Project.

- First, please check your installed package, and update it to the latest version.
- Second, check .net runtime on your Server and update
  it to the latest version.
- Third, check Swagger's dependency on your
  project.

  app.UseOpenApi().UseSwaggerUi3();

After all, if you get the error, please send a full error description here. You can find the logged errors in the Windows event log.

Comment: thank you, my problem solved with updating my .net runtime to latest version.